# SwiftUI @StateObject inside List rows

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI doesn't seem to persist `@StateObjects` for list rows, when the row is embedded inside a container like a stack or `NavigationLink`. Here's an example:

```swift
class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("INIT") }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<40) { _ in
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Dest")) {
                ListRow()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListRow: View {
    @StateObject var obj = MyObject()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Row")
    }
}
```

As you scroll down the list, you see `"INIT"` logged for each new row that appears. But scroll back up, and you see `"INIT"` logged again for every row - even though they've already appeared.

Now remove the `NavigationLink`:

```swift
List(0..<40) { _ in
    ListRow()
}
```

and the `@StateObject` behaves as expected: exactly one `"INIT"` for every row, with no repeats. The `ObservableObject` is persisted across view refreshes.

What rules does SwiftUI follow when persisting `@StateObjects`? In this example `MyObject` might be storing important state information or downloading remote assets - so how do we ensure it only happens once for each row (when combined with `NavigationLink`, etc)?

Comment: The `ListRow` probably shouldn't store any `@StateObject`s. Instead, they should be persisted _outside_ of the row, then passed in when the `ListRow` is initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what documentation says about `StateObject`:

```
///     @StateObject var model = DataModel()
///
/// SwiftUI creates a new instance of the object only once for each instance of
/// the structure that declares the object.
```

and `List` really does not create new instance of row, but reuses created before and went offscreen. However `NavigationLink` creates new instance for label every time, so you see this.

Possible solution for your case is to move `NavigationLink` *inside* `ListRow`:

```
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<40) { _ in
            ListRow()
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
struct ListRow: View {
    @StateObject var obj = MyObject()
    var body: some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: Text("Dest")) {     // << here !!
          Text("Row")
       }
    }
}
```

You can even separate them if, say, you want to reuse `ListRow` somewhere without navigation

```
struct LinkListRow: View {
    @StateObject var obj = MyObject()
    var body: some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: Text("Dest")) {
          ListRow(obj: obj)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Once for each instance of the structure that declares the object`. This is why it's so easy for bugs to creep in - there's no guarantee (or documentation) of *when* a new instance will be created, it just happens sometimes by surprise. `NavigationLink` and `Stacks` are 2 examples - they recreate their contents even when their containing view is supposed to be "preserved".